# C++ add x amount of chars to string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I have an array that holds strings. I was wondering if there's any way to add X amount of chars to the string in the array.

For example if a user inputs the number 10 and then the letter A, I want stringarray[x] to have the value of AAAAAAAAAA.

At the moment I am using a for-loop but I was wondering if there is an easier and more efficient way of doing this. One that doesn't require a loop.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cctype>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
char letter;
int number;
        string stringarray[5] = {" "};
cin >> letter; // letter to add
cin >> number; // number of times
cout << stringarray[1]; // here I want the result to be letter x number
    return 0;

}
```

I can only use these libraries. 
I don't think it's necessary to post my for-loop since it already works. I am only wondering if there's any way to do it without the loop.

Comment: Some code would be swell.

Comment: @teadyber Explain your anarchic indentation.

Answer (score 2):

A C++ way of doing this is to use `std::string s(10, 'A');` and get `const char *stringarray = s.c_str()` from it if you need a `const char *`.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please explain why you downvote this answer. The OP's question is clear: "For example if a user inputs the number 10 and then the letter A, I want stringarray[x] to have the value of AAAAAAAAAA without using loop".

Comment: @Downvoter I agree I think this is the best way to do this.